# Postgres SCD Type 1 program updating all rows instead of matching rows, unmatched rows will be updated as NULL

Tags: postgresql, scd

Postgres SCD Type 1 program updating all rows instead of only to those matching rows, those unmatched row will be updated as blank.

```
-- Create table tableToBeUpdated
CREATE TABLE "TEST"."TABLETOBEUPDATED" (
    "Z" character varying(5),
    "ID" integer,
    "Y" integer
);

-- Insert data into tableToBeUpdated
INSERT INTO "TEST"."TABLETOBEUPDATED" ("Z", "ID", "Y")
VALUES
    ('one', 1, 50),
    ('two', 2, 30),
    ('three', 3, 30),
    ('four', 4, 60),
    ('five', 5, 70),
    ('six', 6, 80);
    
    
-- Create table tableB
CREATE TABLE "TEST"."TABLEB" (
    "ID" integer,
    "NEWY" integer
);

-- Insert data into tableB
INSERT INTO "TEST"."TABLEB" ("ID", "NEWY")
VALUES
    (1, 500),
    (2, 233),
    (3, 300),
    (4, 472),
    (5, 111);
    

UPDATE "TEST"."TABLETOBEUPDATED"
SET "Y" = (
    SELECT "NEWY"
    FROM "TEST"."TABLEB"
    WHERE "TABLETOBEUPDATED"."ID" = "TABLEB"."ID"
);

SELECT * FROM "TEST"."TABLETOBEUPDATED"
```

Run the above program will produce the following result.

[image: Row number 6, Y has been updated as NULL]

Expected result should be as follow.

[image: Intended result]

Appreciate if anyone could help to correct my Postgres SQL program above. Thank you in advance.

Comment: There is no where condition for your update statement, only for the sub query. Obviously the database will update every record, some with a null

Answer (score 0):

You can create a subquery for this process as follows.

```
UPDATE "TEST"."TABLETOBEUPDATED" 
SET "Y" = "x"."NEWY" 
FROM (
    SELECT "ID","NEWY"
    FROM "TEST"."TABLEB"  
) AS x
WHERE "TEST"."TABLETOBEUPDATED"."ID" = "x"."ID" and x."NEWY" is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not specify a `where` clause your update statement tells postgres to *update **every row** to the result of the following sub-select*. For item z=>'six' that query sets the value to `null` as a result of no matching row for the sub-select. You can either supply an appropriate `where` clause or you could use the result of that query as the leading column of the `coalesce()` function and supply the existing `y` value as the training column. See [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL). Your query then becomes: (see [demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/JW9G4ecS))

```
update tabletobeupdated
set y = coalesce(
                  (select newy
                     from tableb
                    where tabletobeupdated.id = tableb.id
                  )
                  , y
                );
```